# How To Release Product (Invoke Method Publish) After Completion EAI Siebel Adapter.Insert?

Tags: siebel

I've created the inbound Web Service (based on WF). 
There is a step "Upsert Products" in my WF:
BusService: EAI Siebel Adapter
Method: Upsert

After completion of the WF (if there were any new products) I've got new products which I can see at the "Administration - Product / Product Definition" view with the checked "Locked flag" field. So to make this product available to user I have to push the button "Release" (it invokes Publish method of BusComp "Internal Product - ISS Admin")
Is there any way to invoke this method (Publish) in the my WF
immediately after the step "Upsert Products"?

Thanks in advance.
Sergey

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ISS Authoring Import Export Service` business service, method `ReleaseSingleObject`. The method is not visible under the business service definition. Check the vanilla workflow `SWI Initial Load Non CP Order Release` which has a step which uses the service to release products. Check in the flat view of siebel tools to find out other vanilla workflows which uses the `ReleaseSingleObject` method.